# Python - Get decimal value from request and insert in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask, floating-point

I have a MySQL db with a Museum table:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idMuseums   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nameMuseums | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| City        | varchar(60)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Lat         | decimal(9,6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Lon         | decimal(9,6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

With an Android client I send gps coordinates to the Python server through StringRequest with these parameters:

```
//some code
params.put("lat", String.format("%.6f",lat));       
params.put("lon", String.format("%.6f",lon));
Log.d(IDENTIFIER,"lat lon in request: "+String.format("%.6f",lat)+" "+String.format("%.6f",lon));

^----in log the coordinates are correct and they have a comma, e.g. 45,451691 9,161442
```

So, in the server (using Flask), I would like to add the new Museum and I tried this:

```
try:
    m = Museum(id=0, name=request.form['name'], city=request.form['city'], lat=request.form['lat'], lon=request.form['lon'])
    db.session.add(m)
    db.session.commit()
    return '', 200
except Exception as e:
    db.session.rollback()
    return e
```

The problem is:

1. if I use `lat=request.form['lat'], lon=request.form['lon']`
   like in the example I don't get the digits after the comma in the db (e.g. 45.000000 9.000000)
2. if I use `lat=float(request.form['lat']), lon=float(request.form['lon'])`
   I get `TypeError: 'exceptions.ValueError' object is not callable`
3. if I use `lat=Decimal(request.form['lat']), lon=Decimal(request.form['lon'])` 
   I get `TypeError: 'InvalidOperation' object is not callable`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share `request.form` data?

Comment: @yogkm Sorry, I did not understand what you asked me. In Python I have that function called when I access one URL, in Android I put four parameters: I get name and city from two EditTexts and I format lat lon after calculating them from address with Geocode. At first lat lon are two `double` variables, for example, 45.4516914 9.161441700000001 but after the format they are 45,451691 9,161442.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses a dot character (period) as the decimal separator in numeric literals, not a comma character.

To insert decimal values, the SQL statement would be something like this

```
  ( ..., lat, lon, ...)  VALUES  ( ... , '45.451691' , '9.161442' , ...)
  --                                        ^            ^
```

---

With the comma character in the string, MySQL is dropping the comma and everything after the comma.

As a demonstration of what's going on, consider:

```
 SELECT '123.456789' + 0 
      , '123,456789' + 0
      , '123derpity' + 0
```

---

References:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/number-literals.html

> Numbers may include . as a decimal separator.

Comment: You're right! If I want the dot instead of comma I can use `String.format(Locale.US,"%.6f",lat)` and it works! Thanks